# Chinese character garbled for one line

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

I have 6 columns in one table and one of the column contains Chinese character and I have 200 records in that table.

I have written the code to save it one text file. The problem is while fetching all records, I am able to see the chinese text in the file. But while fetching only one record I am seeing the Chinese text is garbled.

I am using the below code.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
String outputFile = fileNameEncode("C:\\a\a.txt");
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
writeToFile(os);
}

private static String fileNameEncode(String name) {
        String file;
        try {
            byte[] utf_byte = name.getBytes("UTF-8");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);

            for (byte b : utf_byte) {
                int integer = b & 0xFF; // drop the minus sign
                sb.append((char) integer);
            }
            file = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            file = name;
        }
        return file;
    }

    public void writeToFile(FileOutputStream os) {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(ostream, "GBK")));

        for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < arrayList.size(); rowNum++) {//arrayList contains data from db
                ArrayList list = arrayList.get(rowNum);

                    for(int k = 0; k < list.size(); k++{
                    String[] data = new String[6];
                        for (int colNum = 0; colNum < 6; colNum++) {
                            data[colNum] = list.get(i).toString();
                        }

                        String outLine = composeLine(data, ctlInfo);                    

                        // write the line
                        pw.print(outLine);
                        pw.println();

            }
            }

}
    private static String composeLine(String[] data, ControlInfo ctl) {
        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
        String delim = ","
        int elemCount = data.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < elemCount; i++) {
            if (i > 0)
                line.append(delim);
           if (data[i] != null && (data[i].contains("\n") || data[i].contains("\r") ||
                    data[i].contains("\r\n"))){
                data[i] = data[i].replaceAll("(\\t|\\r?\\n)+", " ");
            }
            else {
                line.append(data[i]);
            }
        }

        return line.toString();
    }
```

could you please let me know where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the code is good, the problem is in notepad++. If the character set in node pad ++ is Chinese(GB2312) then I am able to see the correct text. The note pad ++ is auto set GB2312 for two lines but for one line it is not doing auto set to GB2312.